# Simpson rule for double integral

Tags: numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

Compute a quadrature of

$\int_c^d\int_a^b  f(x,y)dxdy$

using the Simpson rule and estimate the error.

So the Simpson rule says

$S(f) = (b-a)/6(f(a)+4f((a+b)/2) +f(b))$

So i get

$\int_c^d(b-a)/6(f(a)+4f((a+b)/2) +f(b))dy$

Is that even correct? How do I go on?

Comment: Are you looking for the general theory or is there a specific $f(x, y)$ and limits?

Comment: General theory, there is a part exercise with a specific function, but I think I'll be able to do this then

Comment: Try: http://jmahaffy.sdsu.edu/courses/s10/math541/lectures/pdf/week09/lecture.pdf and http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture32.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to get you started. Define an operator:
$$
I_x(f) := \int_a^b f(x) \, dx
$$
We can see that $I_x(f + g) = I_x(f) + I_x(g)$ and if $\alpha$ does not depend on $x$, $I_x(\alpha f) = \alpha I_x(f)$. In other words the operator is linear.

If it acts on $f(x, y)$ it returns a function of $y$ only.

By analogy define another operator
$$
I_y(f) := \int_c^d f(y) \, dy
$$

Applying $I_x$ and $I_y$ consequently we get a double integral:
$$
I_y(I_x(f)) := \int_c^d \left[ \int_a^b f(x, y) \, dx \right] dy .
$$

Now define a "Simpson's rule" operator:
$$
S_x(f) := (f(a) + 4 f((a+b)/2) + f(b)) (b - a)/6
$$
It is also linear and if it acts on $f(x, y)$ it "kills" dependency on $x$. The same for $S_y$:
$$
S_y(f) := (f(c) + 4 f((c+d)/2) + f(d)) (d - c)/6
$$

By analogy with integral let compute $S_y(S_x(f(x, y)))$ and call it Simpson's rule for double integral. Apply $S_x$ to f(x, y):
$$
S_x(f(x, y)) = (f(a, y) + 4 f((a+b)/2, y) + f(b, y)) (b - a)/6
$$
and apply $S_y$ to the result using linearity
$$
S_y(S_x(f(x, y)) = (S_y(f(a, y)) + 4 S_y(f((a+b)/2, y)) + S_y(f(b, y))) (b - a)/6
$$
expand all three terms with $S_y$
$$
S_y(S_x(f(x, y)) = \\
\left(16f\left(\frac{b+a}{2},\frac{d+c}{2}\right)+4f\left(\frac{b+a}{2},d\right)+4f\left(\frac{b+a}{2},c\right)+4f\left(b,\frac{d+c}{2}\right)
                             +f\left(b,d\right)+f\left(b,c\right)+4f\left(a,\frac{d+c}{2}\right)+f\left(a,d\right)+f\left(a,c\right)\right)
 \frac{\left(b-a\right)\left(d-c\right)}{36}
$$

Answer (score 0):

A C implementation for applying Simpson's Rule towards solving double integrals can be found here if you are interested.
[Simpson integration technique for
evaluating  double integrals](https://github.com/adel314/Small-C-Plus--for-TMS9900)

It can be also represented in the following form:

$$
S_x(y_j) = f(x_0, y_j) + f(x_n,y_j) + 4\sum_{i = 1}^{(N_x-2)/2} f(x_{2i-1},y_j) + 2\sum_{i = 1}^{(N_x-2)/2} f(x_{2i},y_j)
$$

$$
S = \frac{h_xh_y}{9}[(S_x(y_0) +S_x(y_n) + 4\sum_{j = 1}^{(N_y-2)/2} S_x(y_{2j-1}) + 2\sum_{j = 1}^{(N_y-2)/2} S_x(y_{2j})
$$

Where
$$
h_x = \frac{UpperLimit_x - LowerLimit_x}{N_x} 
$$

and
$$
h_y = \frac{UpperLimit_y - LowerLimit_y}{N_y} 
$$